# CreateProcessAsUser not executing application from Non-Sys32 directory

Tags: c++, windows, windows-vista

I have written following function in my printer monitor. If I keep my exe in Sys32 directory then it works fine but as L"c:\1\MyApp.exe" it never executes the exe file. I am using Windows VISTA system.

Can anyone help me in this?

```
BOOL StartProcess(PROCESS_INFORMATION *pi, STARTUPINFO *si)
{
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    DWORD dwSessionId = 0,explorerPid = 0;
    HANDLE hUserTokenDup = NULL,hPToken=NULL,hProcess=NULL, hUserToken = NULL;
    DWORD dwCreationFlags, zp;
    LPVOID pEnv =NULL;
    DWORD winlogonSessId;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;
    wchar_t buff[300];

    // get session ID
    dwSessionId = GetSessionID();
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    // Find the explorer.exe process
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;

    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wsprintf(buff,L"StartProcess - INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE %d\n",__LINE__);
        syslog3(buff);
        return FALSE;
    }

    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if (!Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
    {
        wsprintf(buff,L"StartProcess - Process32First fails %d\n",__LINE__);
        syslog3(buff);
        return FALSE;
    }

    do
    {
        if (wcscmp(procEntry.szExeFile, L"explorer.exe") == 0)
        {
            // We found a explorer process...
            // make sure it's running in the console session
            winlogonSessId = 0;
            if (ProcessIdToSessionId(procEntry.th32ProcessID, &winlogonSessId)
                && winlogonSessId == dwSessionId)
            {
                explorerPid = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
    ZeroMemory(si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si->cb= sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si->lpDesktop     = L"winsta0\\default";
    si->wShowWindow   = SW_SHOW;
    si->dwFlags       = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

    //ZeroMemory(pi, sizeof(pi));

    hProcess = OpenProcess(MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, FALSE, explorerPid);

    if(!::OpenProcessToken(hProcess,TOKEN_DUPLICATE|TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY|TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID
        |TOKEN_READ|TOKEN_WRITE,&hPToken))
    {
        SendInfoMessage(TEXT(LNG_ERROR_OPEN_TOKEN),MB_OK, &zp);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL,SE_DEBUG_NAME,&luid))
    {
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid =luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes =SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if(!DuplicateTokenEx(hPToken,MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,NULL,
        SecurityIdentification,TokenPrimary,&hUserTokenDup))
    {
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    SetTokenInformation(hUserTokenDup,
        TokenSessionId,(void*)dwSessionId,sizeof(DWORD));

    if(!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hUserTokenDup,FALSE,&tp,sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,NULL))
    {
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    pEnv = NULL;
    if(CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv,hUserTokenDup,TRUE))
    {
        dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
    }
    else
        pEnv = NULL;

    wsprintf(buff,L"Now Executing File %d\n",__LINE__);
    syslog3(buff);
    // Launch the process in the client's logon session.
    bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(
        hUserTokenDup,                  // client's access token
        L"C:\\1\\MyApp.exe",             
        NULL,                           // command line
        NULL,                           // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        NULL,                           // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        FALSE,                          // handles are not inheritable
        dwCreationFlags,                // creation flags
        pEnv,                           // pointer to new environment block
        NULL,                           // name of current directory
        si,                             // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        pi                              // receives information about new process
        );


    RevertToSelf();
    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnv);
    wsprintf(buff,L"After Executing File %d\n",__LINE__);
    syslog3(buff);

Cleanup: 
    //Perform All the Close Handles tasks
    if (hUserToken != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        CloseHandle(hUserToken);
    if (hProcess != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    if (hUserTokenDup != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        CloseHandle(hUserTokenDup);
    if (hPToken != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        CloseHandle(hPToken);

    return bResult;
}
```

Comment: What value does CreateProcessAsUser return?  If it returns zero (indicating an error), what does the GetLastError() function return?

Comment: I do not get return value of the CreateProcessAsUser function and hence not able to check the GetLastError value. For exe present in Sys32 directory I get return value as 0 for CreateProcessAsUser function.

Comment: @NatashsaD You do get a return value. You can't not get a return value from a function! You store it in `bResult`. Pray tell, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote "but as L"c:\1\MyApp.exe" it never executes the exe file". Did you mean L"c:\\1\\MyApp.exe" ? Check the return value from GetLastError(). It could be access rights on NTFS / file not found or any number of other things, knowing the error code will get you started.